1980's/1990's French comedy where a husband fabricates a fake daughter
I'm trying to identify a 1980's/1990's French language movie I saw on TV, but I don't know any actors names. It is a "farce" type comedy movie in which a 50 year old man takes a twenty-something girl (character name Julie) home and then his wife comes home to find them (innocently) talking. The man and the girl then spend the ENTIRE film fabricating and spinning a huge complicated story to his wife, of how the girl is not "a girlfriend", but his daughter from a previous marriage. The wife asks the girl to stay in their big house, goes shopping with her, invites her to her huband's birthday party, where the girl's mother turns up, gets drunk and carries on the roll of the man's Ex wife.

Sounds like the French comedy Happy Easter from 1984, but the husband isn't exactly innocent... From an online synopsis:

Stephane [Jean-Paul Belmondo] can't resist having affairs, but he always manages to get home in time to prevent his wife from being suspicious about his activities. One day he sends his wife off for a long trip during Easter but the trip is cancelled. She arrives back home just as Stephane's young girlfriend Julie [Sophie Marceau] is about to remove her blouse. Stephane struggles for a credible explanation for Julie's presence, and finally admits to a secret he'd been keeping for a long time - Julie is his daughter! This story works out very well for a while and his wife even invites her newly discovered stepdaughter to stay with them. And so the adventure begins...

Here's the trailer:




You absolute hero! Thanks a million for that. Much appreciated! :-)

@Martyn No problem, but don't forget to click on the check mark to approve the answer.
